# Custom PHP Mailer attachment not attached with email

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, mailer

I have customize mailer function where except file attachment, rest of things are working well. To make it simplify, I have added only code related to attachment. As output, I can see file uploaded to server but it's going to attach in email. I am getting all details in email except file attachment. it's customize mailer class which I have created but not sure why attachment not sending to email.

**Mailer.class.php**

```
<?php
class Mailer 
{

private $addAttachment = [];

public function addAttachment($addAttachment)
    {   
        if (empty($addAttachment))
        {
            $this->setError('No Attachments','empty');
        }else{
             $this->addAttachment[] = $addAttachment;
             echo $addAttachment;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

For Sending **test.php**

```
require_once 'Mailer.class.php';

$toemails = array("my_email_address@gmail.com"); 
$toemail = implode(',', $toemails);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $attachment = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $folder = '/uploads/';
    $file_name1 = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);

    print_r($_FILES);
    $mailer = new Mailer(true);

    $mailer->setToEmail($toemail)
               ->setFromName(isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:'')
               ->setFromEmail(isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'')
               ->setSubject('Application Regarding'.$_POST['Title'])
               ->addAttachment('/uploads/'.$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])
               ->setBody($body)
               ->run();
                exit();

        if(!$mailer->sendMail()) {
            echo "Something has gone wrong, please contact the site administrator or try again.";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Email Successfully Submitted"; 
        }

        print "</pre>"; 
    }
?>
```

print_r($_FILES) gives me following Output for attachment:

```
Array
(
    [uploaded_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Image_Manager.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phplBV7gV
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 150300
        )
  )
```

Comment: Which version of PHPMailer are you using?

Comment: @Martin I do not see any errors in logs

Comment: Does the uploaded file actually exist at the designated position; as set by `move_uploaded_file()` ?

Comment: @Martin it was totally custom PHPMailer and I did not have addattachment function which I have added now.

Comment: `echo $addAttachment;` this looks out of place

Comment: @Martin I can see file at designated position but not attached to email and I have got so many email without attachment.. sending email is working without attachment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208604/discussion-between-nisarg-and-martin).

Comment: @Nisarg  You need to use a full server/system path. That's why it's failing. I.e.: `->addAttachment('/var/usr/public/uploads/'....`

Comment: it's not working. I have tried with full path -`>addAttachment('/var/www/www.abc.com/resumes/Image_Manager.pdf')`

Comment: This question is not using PHPMailer at all so I removed the PHPMailer tag.